# Lawnchair.js not updating data

Tags: javascript, lawnchair

I've got a "LocalStore" object for storing data locally.  It's based around a Lawnchair object.

```
var LocalStore = function(name) {
    var that = this;
    that.name = name;

    that.lawnchair = Lawnchair({ name: that.name }, function(store) {
        this.before('save', function(record){
            console.log("saving " + that.name);
            console.log(record);
        });

        this.after('save', function(record){
            console.log("saved " + that.name);
            console.log(record);
            that.getData(function(records){
                console.log("now it's this");
                console.log(records);
            });
        });
    });

    that.getData = function(callback) {
        that.lawnchair.get(that.name, callback);
    };
};
```

LocalStore is then extended with `_.extend`(from the Underscore.js library) with this method:

```
save: function(collection, callback) {
        this.lawnchair.save({ key:this.name, value: collection }, function(record) {
            callback(record);
        });
    }
```

This code is used to update a Backbone.js Collection object to Lawnchair.  The first time "save" runs for my Users Collection it saves correctly and shows that the object is a simple  key/value pair where value is an Array.

Later in my code when a User selects a Default Project, I modify the Users Collection and call "save" again with an updated "defaultProjectId" on the User.  The code runs error free, but the `after('save')` code for Lawnchair runs and shows me that:
- The `record` object returned is a key/value pair where value is a full Backbone.js Collection with the defaultProjectId property set correctly.
- The `getData` method that grabs the latest from the Database still shows as a key/value pair with value a simple Array and defaultProjectId is set incorrectly.

I'm at a loss as what to do.  It should just be simply calling "lawnchair.save" updates the record, but it just doesn't do it.

Comment: Why do you use extend to add the function? Are you adding the function to the LocalStore *function* or to an instance created using new LocalStore()?

Comment: Can you post the Users collection code as well and/or put it up on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this jsfiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/QUgtg/1/

I have recreated your code. Instead of a backbone collection, I am passing in an array of objects. This seems to work. You can see the logging output in Firebug.

I have used my own extend code to add the `save()`. Though honestly, I don't see why you would want to do it that way, instead of just adding a property to the prototype. Your code may differ in that aspect.

If what I have posted works on your end, could you modify that code to show what are you doing differently? If possible, recreate the issue on jsfiddle...

Comment: I fiddled with your fiddle and ended up with [this] (http://jsfiddle.net/QUgtg/7/)...which didn't actually change anything about what I was doing but it did cause me to go examine my code again and I realized that I my code was trying to save my key as my array index and value as my key....so you get the points because you made me go look again for the 50th time and see my mistake finally.